# Why did PostgreSQL merge users and groups into roles?

Tags: postgresql, roles, database-permissions

From [the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html):

> The concept of roles subsumes the concepts of "users" and "groups". In
>   PostgreSQL versions before 8.1, users and groups were distinct kinds
>   of entities, but now there are only roles. Any role can act as a user,
>   a group, or both.

Why did they make this change in 8.1?

Perhaps it's easier from the C coders point of view, with a single Role class (struct)?

[More details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-membership.html):

`CREATE USER is equivalent to CREATE ROLE except that CREATE USER` *gives the LOGIN permission to the user/role*.

(I'm about to design a permission system for my webapp, hence I'm interested in this.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The merge has many advantages and no disadvantages. For instance, you can now seamlessly convert a "user" to a "group" and vice versa by adding / removing the `LOGIN` privilege.

```
ALTER ROLE myrole LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE myrole NOLOGIN;
```

Or you can [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) membership in any other login ("user") or non-login role ("group") to a role:

```
GRANT joe TO sue;
```

You can still:

```
CREATE USER james;
```

That's just a [role with login privilege](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) now. Or:

```
CREATE GROUP workers;
```

That's effectively [the same as `CREATE ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creategroup.html) now.

The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) has it all.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this thread in the PostgreSQL-Hackers list](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2003/06/groups-and-roles/064or6pfpvihyl2s7uhklvqu5tti/200306105wtoocpuftkqllpjna7zglfmgu#20030618h6py7zlzhgpbwij5ak3d4zrpue), from June 6, 2003, that in the end suggests that users and groups and roles be consolidated. (Thanks Craig Ringer for suggesting that I check the pgsql-hackers list archives.)

Here are some benefits mentioned (those that I found).

> allow groups to have groups as members
>
> the ACL code would be simplified
>
> the GRANT/REVOKE syntax and the display format for ACL lists could be
>   simplified, since there'd be no need for a syntactic marker as to
>   whether a given name is a user or a group.
>
> In some circumstances I could see it making sense to allow logging in
>   directly as a group/role/whatchacallit
>
> This would also solve the problem that information_schema views will
>   show only owned objects
>
> [makes it easier to] representing privileges granted to groups [since
>   you'd simply reuse the role related code?]

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html):

> The SQL standard defines the concepts of users and roles, but it
>   regards them as distinct concepts and leaves all commands defining
>   users to be specified by each database implementation. In PostgreSQL
>   we have chosen to unify users and roles into a single kind of entity.
>   Roles therefore have many more optional attributes than they do in the
>   standard.

Comment: That's something you should ask the hackers who did it, not some forum like SO.

Comment: @FrankHeikens then your answer completely misses the point, which you even aknowledge...

Answer (score 3):

Having a distinction between users and groups doesn't gain you anything.

AFAIK the motivation for changing it was to simplify uses like:

- One user masquerading as another, eg a superuser simulating a reduced permissions user. With unified roles this becomes just another change of current role, no different to changing primary group.
- Groups that are members of other groups to implement granular access permissions.

If you want the details, though, you're best off checking out the archives of the pgsql-hackers list for the period, and the git history (converted from CVS).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the archives of the pgsql-hackers list. I found a relevant thread, and added another answer to this question.