# PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I'm setting up my PostgreSQL 9.1. I can't do anything with PostgreSQL: can't `createdb`, can't `createuser`; all operations return the error message

```
Fatal: role h9uest does not exist
```

`h9uest` is my account name, and I `sudo apt-get install` PostgreSQL 9.1 under this account.
Similar error persists for the `root` account.

Comment: Afterwards you might run into `FATAL:  role "user" is not permitted to log in`, check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57723/superuser-is-not-permitted-to-login for that.

Comment: I answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31712520/3637498). Read this tutorial too "[How to Install Postgres for Ubuntu Linux](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-install-postgres-for-linux)".

Comment: @Ruzenhack that tutorial link was exactly what I needed! Very clear and simple

Comment: psql -h localhost -U postgres

Comment: If you get the error `role doesn't exist` AND the error `can't create role, it already exists` check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658832/1689770

Comment: How worst can `postgresql` authentication be?

Comment: I ran into this trying to connect to a local Postgres container from DataGrip, and I had to configure the authentication method to be User & Password, set user to postgres, and leave password blank (using NoAuth, Datagrip tried to use my OS username as the role)

Answer (score 1073, accepted):

Use the *operating system user* `postgres` to create your database - as long as you haven't set up a *database* role with the necessary privileges that corresponds to your operating system user of the same name (`h9uest` in your case):

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

As recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/q/359856/98376) or [here](https://serverfault.com/q/601140/98376).

Then try again. Type `exit` when done with operating as system user `postgres`.

**Or** execute the single command `createuser` as `postgres` with `sudo`, like [demonstrated by
dsrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708583/939860) in another answer.

The point is to use the operating system user matching the database role of the same name to be granted access via [**`ident` authentication**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html). `postgres` is the default operating system user to have initialized the database cluster. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/database-roles.html)

> In order to bootstrap the database system, a freshly initialized
> system always contains one predefined role. This role is always a
> “superuser”, and by default (unless altered when running `initdb`) it
> will have the same name as the operating system user that initialized
> the database cluster. Customarily, this role will be named `postgres`.
> In order to create more roles you first have to connect as this
> initial role.

I have heard of odd setups with non-standard user names or where the operating system user does not exist. You'd need to adapt your strategy there.

Read about [database roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html) and [client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) in the manual.

Comment: It is impossible to run `sudo etc` as user postgres... How to install a program?  See [this S2geometry installation problem](https://github.com/AfieldTrails/s2-postgis/issues/2).

Comment: Depending on the configuration, one might simply need `su postgres`.

Comment: `sudo -u postgres` doesn't work, while `sudo -u postgres -i` works! What does the `-i` flag do?

Comment: @parsecer: An interactive shell is started, similar to `su`, but based on sudo privileges. See `man sudo`.

Comment: WIth Postgres 12, I had to change `-u` to `-U` and I get "invalid option -- 'i'".

Comment: I ran into the "postgres user does not exist" problem when restoring global roles and permissions from a backup file on a Mac.  I found that I could just specify my Mac system user, i.e., 
`psql -U <mac_user> -d template1 -f <globals/backup/file>`.  Is there anything wrong with that approach?  After doing that, the database roles include my regular system username (as well as a `postgres` user); I don't know if that's a security risk.

Answer (score 356):

After trying many other people's solutions, and without success, this answer finally helped me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974197/2433309

In short, running

```
sudo -u postgres createuser owning_user
```

creates a role with name owning_user (in this case, h9uest). After that you can run `rake db:create` from the terminal under whatever account name you set up without having to enter into the Postgres environment.

Comment: If you get an "insufficient privileges" error after this, you could append the -s flag to the above command. This will create your new user as a superuser. Please be aware of the security implications of this should you decide to do it.

Comment: how to do this with homebrew?

Comment: I'm getting "insufficient privileges", but now I get ERROR: roll "username" already exists.

Comment: @ConnorLeech You can replace 'postgres' with the name of your PG super user. In my case it was my name.

Comment: I also had to use `-s`, and did not need to use `sudo -u postgres` (just `createuser new_user` worked fine)

Comment: `psql: FATAL:  role "jonny" does not exist` okay so 
`sudo -u postgres -s createuser jonny` then why 
`createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "jonny" already exists`

Comment: @Jonathan Drop using "sudo -u postgres dropuser jonny"

Comment: The original answer has fewer up-votes, LOL!!

Comment: If you get "insufficient privileges" error and you do not want to create your user as `superuser`. Then basically create a user with `CREATEDB` attribute like explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/role-attributes.html#ROLE-ATTRIBUTES).

Answer (score 179):

```
sudo su - postgres

psql template1
```

creating role on pgsql with privilege as "superuser"

```
CREATE ROLE username superuser;
eg. CREATE ROLE demo superuser;
```

Then create user

```
CREATE USER username; 
eg. CREATE USER demo;
```

Assign privilege to user

```
GRANT ROOT TO username;
```

And then enable login that user, so you can run e.g.: `psql template1`, from normal `$` terminal:

```
ALTER ROLE username WITH LOGIN;
```

Comment: I just did a new install of PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and was able to use the follow to create a new superuser:


```CREATE ROLE username superuser createdb login;```

which combines all three steps...

Comment: # GRANT ROOT to me;
ERROR:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: simpler version:     
```sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER;
sudo -u postgres createdb $USER```

Comment: @shacker `#GRANT postgres TO username`

Comment: I am using root to start the server then ```psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 --command "CREATE USER postgresondocker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'postgresondocker';" &&\
    createdb -O postgresondocker postgresondocker`` can I use root to do this if I add it to the pg_ident?

Answer (score 147):

This works for me:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Comment: please add the password for above user.

Comment: @Vincent if the password was never changed after PostgreSQL installation, by default it is `postgres` (tested on Linux and Windows).

Comment: `role postgres does not exist`

Comment: To access a specific database you'll need to specify the db name
```psql -h hostname -U username -d database_name```

Answer (score 117):

Installing postgres using `apt-get` does not create a user role or a database.

To create a superuser role and a database for your personal user account:

`sudo -u postgres createuser -s $(whoami); createdb $(whoami)`

Comment: I needed to run the second part as:
`sudo -u postgres createdb $(whoami)`

Comment: @SanD If you’ve created your own user account as a super user (via the `-s` flag in the first command), you can create the database as yourself. You won’t need to run `createdb` as `postgres`.

Answer (score 40):

```
psql postgres

postgres=# CREATE ROLE username superuser;
postgres=# ALTER ROLE username WITH LOGIN;
```

Comment: `psql postgres` results: `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

Comment: `psql postgres -U postgres`? Depends on the user (-U) you have.

Comment: thank you! I struggled how to backup postgresql with root since I dont know postgres password

Comment: I get an error "must be a superuser to create a superuser"

Answer (score 25):

I did a healthcheck with docker-compose.

```
healthcheck:
  test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'pg_isready']
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 5
```

If you also have that change the user:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'pg_isready -U postgres'] # <<<---
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 5
```

Answer (score 23):

For version **Postgres 9.5**  use following comand:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 19):

Working method,

1. `vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`
2. `local   all             postgres                                peer`
   here change **peer** to **trust**
3. restart, `sudo service postgresql restart`
4. now try, `psql -U postgres`

Comment: It should be obvious that the `trust` method is only advisable in a completely secure environment. While access from untrusted connections is possible, *never* expose your DB cluster like that.

Comment: Check:  If the postgresql service is not started, possibly there can be some error in the file `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 11):

For **Windows** users : `psql -U postgres`

You should see then the command-line interface to PostgreSQL: `postgres=#`

Comment: Thanks man. This worked for me on windows.

Answer (score 8):

In local user prompt, not root user prompt, type

```
sudo -u postgres createuser <local username>
```

Then enter password for local user.

Then enter the previous command that generated "role 'username' does not exist."

Above steps solved the problem for me.
If not, please send terminal messages for above steps.

Answer (score 8):

I installed it on macOS and had to:

```
cd /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin
createuser -U postgres -s YOURUSERNAME
createdb YOURUSERNAME
```

Here's the source: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/313#issuecomment-192461641

Answer (score 5):

**Manually creating a DB cluster solved it in my case.**

For some reason, when I installed postgres, the "initial DB" wasn't created. Executing [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) did the trick for me.

This solution is provided in [the PostgreSQL Wiki - First steps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps):

> **initdb**
>
> Typically installing postgres to your OS creates an "initial DB" and starts the postgres server daemon running. If not then you'll need to [run initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER

sudo -u postgres createdb $USER
```

This should definitely work for you.

Answer (score 2):

dump and restore with `--no-owner --no-privileges` flags

e.g.

dump - `pg_dump --no-owner --no-privileges --format=c --dbname=postgres://userpass:username@postgres:5432/schemaname > /tmp/full.dump`

restore - `pg_restore --no-owner --no-privileges --format=c --dbname=postgres://userpass:username@postgres:5432/schemaname /tmp/full.dump`

Answer (score 0):

for those who using docker and correctly followed the instructions from official doc, if you still met this problem, RESTART windows and try again.

Answer (score -2):

Follow These Steps and it Will Work For You :

1. run `msfconsole`
2. type db_console
3. some information will be shown to you  chose the information who tell you to make: `db_connect user:pass@host:port.../database` sorry I don't remember it    but it's like this one then replace the user and the password and the host and the  database with the information included in the `database.yml` in the emplacement: `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/config`
4. you will see. rebuilding the model cache in the background.
5. Type apt-get update && apt-get upgrade after the update restart the terminal and lunch msfconsole and it works you can check that by typing in `msfconsole:  msf>db_status` you will see that it's connected.