# Which version of PostgreSQL am I running?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

I'm in a corporate environment (running Debian Linux) and didn't install it myself. I access the databases using Navicat or phpPgAdmin (if that helps). I also don't have shell access to the server running the database.

Answer (score 2075, accepted):

Run this query from PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT version();
```

Comment: No result in my case in terminal on Ubuntu

Comment: @Timo, this is a query to be run through PostgreSQL. This could be done through pgAdmin, or any other mechanism for running a query. Were you trying to run it from an Ubuntu shell? (this won't work)

Comment: This can also be ran from the command line with `psql -c 'SELECT version();'`

Comment: You can running directly from the bash specifying the postgres db as follow: `psql postgres -c 'SELECT version();'`

Comment: This results in "FATA: role "username" does not exist

Comment: @Frank H. Using: `sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c 'SELECT version()' | grep PostgreSQL` should get you past "role 'username' does not exist".

Comment: To those who have issue with "role 'username' does not exist":
`psql -d postgres -c 'SELECT version();'` (new option `-d postgress`) should fix your problem
`FATAL:  database "..." does not exist` should apply this addditional option as well.

Comment: SHOW server_version;

Comment: For a pure numerical version for programmatic checks use `SHOW server_version_num;`

Comment: Works for AWS RDS Aurora with PosgreSQL too.

Answer (score 676):

I believe this is what you are looking for,

Server version:

```sh
pg_config --version
```

Client version:

```sh
psql --version
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for when shell access is available. Unfortunately in my case I don't have that access; I've updated the question.

Comment: Sometimes the client version is what you want to know anyway.

Comment: As Frank notes, this can be deceiving. psql will connect to whatever postmaster/postgres database process is running and the database engine may not be the same version as the psql command.

Comment: `pg_config --version` could be misleading, e.g. if you upgrade an Ubuntu server and don't run `pg_upgradecluster`, pg_config will show the new version instead of the one you're still using.

Comment: just this works for me:
`pg_config --version`

The command:
 `psql --version`not works, complains for this:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found`

Answer (score 247):

## Using CLI:

### Server version:

```
$ postgres -V  # Or --version.  Use "locate bin/postgres" if not found.
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
$ postgres -V | awk '{print $NF}'  # Last column is version.
9.6.1
$ postgres -V | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}'  # Major.Minor version
9.6
```

If having more than one installation of PostgreSQL, or if getting the "`postgres: command not found`" error:

```
$ locate bin/postgres | xargs -i xargs -t '{}' -V  # xargs is intentionally twice.
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres -V 
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres -V 
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
```

If `locate` doesn't help, try `find`:

```
$ sudo find / -wholename '*/bin/postgres' 2>&- | xargs -i xargs -t '{}' -V  # xargs is intentionally twice.
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres -V 
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
```

Although `postmaster` can also be used instead of `postgres`, using `postgres` is preferable because `postmaster` is a deprecated alias of `postgres`.

### Client version:

As relevant, [login as `postgres`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11919677/832230).

```
$ psql -V  # Or --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
```

If having more than one installation of PostgreSQL:

```
$ locate bin/psql | xargs -i xargs -t '{}' -V  # xargs is intentionally twice.
/usr/bin/psql -V 
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -V 
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.9
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/psql -V 
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

## Using SQL:

### Server version:

```
=> SELECT version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit

=> SHOW server_version;
 server_version 
----------------
 9.2.9

=> SHOW server_version_num;
 server_version_num 
--------------------
 90209
```

If more curious, try `=> SHOW all;`.

### Client version:

For what it's worth, a shell command can be executed within `psql` to show the client version of the `psql` executable in the path. Note that the running `psql` can potentially be different from the one in the path.

```
=> \! psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.9
```

Comment: Thank you !, the ``SHOW server_version;`` is very handy in scripts to avoid having to parse in the long string of ``SELECT version();``.

Comment: Thanks a lot. People don't realize that for issuing SQL commands you have to know at least one role to connect to the database. But with postgres -V you don't have to know to connect to the database to know its version.

Comment: One line in CLI assuming superuser access: `psql postgres -c "SHOW server_version" -t -A`.  `-t` removes headers, `-A` removes alignment whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for `SHOW server_version_num` in particular, which is handy for inequalities.

Answer (score 82):

If you're using *CLI* and you're a `postgres` *user*, then you can do this:

```
psql -c "SELECT version();"
```

Possible *output*:

```
                                                         version                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.1 (Debian 11.1-3.pgdg80+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2) 4.9.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 51):

The accepted answer is great, but if you need to interact programmatically with PostgreSQL version maybe it's better to do:

```
SELECT current_setting('server_version_num'); -- Returns 90603 (9.6.3)
-- Or using SHOW command:
SHOW server_version_num; -- Returns 90603 too
```

It will return server version as an integer. This is how server version is tested in [PostgreSQL source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/5af2e976d72aa345337596cc986237c57e1146b2/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L748), e.g.:

```
/*
 * This is a C code from pg_dump source.
 * It will do something if PostgreSQL remote version (server) is lower than 9.1.0
 */
if (fout->remoteVersion < 90100)
    /*
     * Do something...
     */
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-preset.html#GUC-SERVER-VERSION-NUM) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE).

Answer (score 38):

Execute command

```
psql -V
```

Where

*V* must be in capital.

Comment: That is the `psql` (client) version, **not** the version of the Postgres **server**.

Comment: To [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23652497): if the answer is wrong but is an answer (like the comment implies), don't recommend deletion: downvote! See, for example, "[You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007)" and "[When an answer answers the wrong question, is it Not An Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185162/284827)". This is an answer. You may not agree with it, but it is an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Many of the answers above return the version of the client not the server.

Answer (score 20):

in shell psql.exe , execute

```
\! psql -V
```

Comment: This will give him the version of the postgre client. I thin that OP is asking for the sql server version.

Answer (score 14):

Using `pgadmin4` it can be seen by double clicking Servers > server_name_here > Properties tab > Version:

Version 3.5:

[image: pgadmin4 show postgres version. Servers > server_name > Properties > Version]

Version 4.1, 4.5:

[image]

Comment: Don't see it. Using pgadmin 4 version 4.1.

Comment: @faintsignal added screenshot for pgadmin4 v4.1, that versioning jump happened pretty quick.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought you were right-clicking the server, which leads to a different "Properties" dialog.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

1. Using command line
   Server:

```
postgres -V
```

Client:

```
psql -V
```

2. Login to postgres then:

```
postgres=# select version();
```

Or from cli:

```
psql -c "SELECT version();"
```

3. Use `VERSION` special variable
   Login as postgres user:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Then:

```
psql -c "\echo :VERSION"
```

Check out this guide [here](https://citizix.com/how-to-check-which-version-of-postgres-is-running-installed/) for full explaination

Answer (score 13):

A simple way is to check the version by typing `psql --version` in terminal

Comment: Note that this will only tell you the client version, which could quite possibly be different to the server. See @simhumileco's answer for the canonical way.

Answer (score 11):

use `VERSION` special variable

```
$psql -c "\echo :VERSION"
```

Comment: The \ commands are supplied by the psql client.  That's not a SQL statement you can put into other clients.  Question was about Navicat etc, which do not support this syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Run this query from PostgreSQL:
SELECT version();

Comment: This advice was posted [10 years earlier on this same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733856/2943403) and can be safely purged from the page.

Answer (score 10):

In my case

```
$psql
postgres=# \g
postgres=# SELECT version();
                                                       version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.4.21 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 10):

The pg_config command will report the directory where the PostgreSQL programs are installed (--bindir), the location of C include files (--includedir) and object code libraries (--libdir), and the version of PostgreSQL (--version):

```
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 9.3.6
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are already using for tool(used DBeaver) to connect PostgreSQL, it will look like this :

[image: See image bellow]

Answer (score 7):

**Useful Queries to Chck [PostgreSQL Database Version](https://orahow.com/check-postgresql-database-version/)**

```
bash-4.1$ psql
postgres=# SELECT version();
postgres=# SHOW server_version;
```

**To Check PostgreSQL Client Version.**

```
bash-4.1$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have shell access to the server (the question mentions op does not have, but in case you have,) on a debian/ubuntu system

```
sudo apt-cache policy postgresql
```

which will output the installed version,

```
postgresql:
  Installed: 9.6+184ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 9.6+184ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 9.6+184ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.6+184ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages
```

where the `Installed: <version>` is the installed postgres package version.

Comment: As a similar idea, I ran `$ yum list` to see that certain Postgresql packages were installed.

Comment: this works well. Could you please state how to upgrade from 9.6 to 10. on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

For the current version of PgAdmin: 4.16 at the time of writing.

1. Select the DB server whose version you need.
2. Click on the properties tab in
   the right pane.

See screenshot below:
[image: PGAdmin 4.16 showing DB version 10.10]

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an old question with many good answers. I found that from version 12 onwards, simply invoking the client tells me what I need to know, but I ran them on the server's shell. Examples below with output.

When I was on version 12:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql"
psql (12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
```

I read this as both the client and the server are at version 12.

After I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.04:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql"
psql (13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-0ubuntu0.21.04.1), server 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
```

It's telling me clearly that the client is on version 13 but the server is still on 12, as I confirmed:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Notice, by the way, this misleading result, at this stage:

```
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)
```

After I [upgraded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372385/how-do-i-install-postgresql-version-14-on-ubuntu-21-04) to version 14:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql"
psql (14.0 (Ubuntu 14.0-1.pgdg21.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Again, I interpret it as both the client and the server being on version 14, confirmed once more:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
14  main    5433 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

This version is, by the way, the same obtained by running the `SELECT version();` query.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t know how reliable this is, but you can get two tokens of version fully automatically:

```sh
psql --version 2>&1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1 "." $2}'
```

So you can build paths to binaries:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/postgres
```

Just replace 9.2 with this command.

Comment: `psql --version` returns the version of the `psql` client, **not** the version of the Postgres server

Answer (score 1):

If `Select version()` returns with Memo try using the command this way:

```
Select version::char(100)
```

or

```
Select version::varchar(100)
```

Comment: `select version()::varchar(100);` worked for me, but was the same as `version()`

Answer (score 0):

i go to the postgres-directory and type in cmd => psql --version

Answer (score 0):

```
~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 16.2 (Ubuntu 16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1)
```

I ran this command on ubuntu CLI and found this version