# psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: macos, postgresql, terminal

I'm a postgres novice.

I installed the postgres.app for mac. I was playing around with the psql commands and I accidentally dropped the postgres database. I don't know what was in it.

I'm currently working on a tutorial: http://www.rosslaird.com/blog/building-a-project-with-mezzanine/

And I'm stuck at `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

ERROR MESSAGE: `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

$ which psql

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
```

This is what prints out of `psql -l`

```
                                List of databases
    Name    |   Owner    | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |     Access privileges     
------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------------
 user       | user       | UTF8     | en_US   | en_US | 
 template0  | user       | UTF8     | en_US   | en_US | =c/user                  +
            |            |          |         |       | user      =CTc/user      
 template1  | user       | UTF8     | en_US   | en_US | =c/user                  +
            |            |          |         |       | user      =CTc/user      
(3 rows)
```

So what are the steps I should take? Delete an everything related to psql and reinstall everything?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Restarting Computer. Ensures Launchd from ```brew services start postresql``` is executed.

Comment: Postgresapp use your computer's login username instead of postgres. You can find out what is your username by typing `whoami` in the terminal. Use this username to login instead.

Comment: while installing through **brew** it also use your computer's login username instead of postgres. so, just login by using your username at terminal or while making connection through **pgAdmin4** 
Thanks @duykhoa

Answer (score 659, accepted):

**NOTE:** If you installed postgres using homebrew, see the comments from @user3402754 and @originalhat below.

Note that the error message does **NOT** talk about a missing database, it talks about a missing role. Later in the login process it might also stumble over the missing database.

But the first step is to check the missing role: What is the output within `psql` of the command `\du` ? On my Ubuntu system the relevant line looks like this:

```
                              List of roles
 Role name |            Attributes             | Member of 
-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
```

If there is not at least one role with `superuser`, then you have a problem :-)

If there is one, you can use that to login. And looking at the output of your `\l` command: The permissions for `user` on the `template0` and `template1` databases are the same as on my Ubuntu system for the superuser `postgres`. So I think your setup simple uses `user` as the superuser. So you could try this command to login:

```
sudo -u user psql user
```

If `user` is really the DB superuser you can create another DB superuser and a private, empty database for him:

```
CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;
CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH OWNER postgres;
```

But since your postgres.app setup does not seem to do this, you also should not. Simple adapt the tutorial.

Comment: For me, the user was not being created - this worked instead `CREATE USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';`     am using postgres v10.

Comment: If you installed Postgres from `homebrew` then you need to run `/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres` in your terminal

Comment: I had to run `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: If you are using a specific version of postgres, then you need to include the version in the path -- `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@11/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: @user3402754  Wow!  Why would `brew` not include creating the user!!

Comment: For M1 Macs: `/opt/homebrew/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: for M1+brew+version: `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: For Homebrew with cellar : `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.7/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: for me on M1 this works for me /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/createuser -s postgres

Comment: On my Macbook M3 the commands were installed to `/opt/homebrew/bin` automatically by homebrew, so `createuser -s postgres` works.

Answer (score 340):

For MAC:

1. Install Homebrew
2. `brew install postgres`
3. `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`
4. `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/<version>/bin/createuser -s postgres` or `/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres` which will just use the latest version.
5. start postgres server manually: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

---

To start server at startup

- `mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

---

Now, it is set up, login using `psql -U postgres -h localhost` or use PgAdmin for GUI.

By default user `postgres` will not have any login password.

Check this site for more articles like this: https://medium.com/@Nithanaroy/installing-postgres-on-mac-18f017c5d3f7

Comment: With the newest brew install you can do `brew services start postgresql` to start postgres

Comment: Step 4 could be `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@<version>/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Comment: Step 3 gives `Permission denied`

Answer (score 294):

The key is "I installed the postgres.app for mac." [This application](http://postgresapp.com/) sets up the local PostgreSQL installation with a database superuser whose role name is the same as your login (short) name.

> When Postgres.app first starts up, it creates the $USER database,
>   which is the default database for psql when none is specified. The
>   default user is $USER, with no password.

Some scripts (e.g., a database backup created with `pgdump` on a Linux systsem) and tutorials will assume the superuser has the traditional role name of `postgres`.

You can make your local install look a bit more traditional and avoid these problems by doing a one time:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.*/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

which will make those **FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist** go away.

Comment: I just did a clean install of Mac OS X Mavericks. I use Postgres.app and Navicat for a GUI to browse databases. Was getting the fatal role does not exist error. Your tip just completely fixed the problem. Migraine averted. 2+ for you! Thanks.

Comment: If you're using postgres from Homebrew, then you want `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin/createuser -s postgres` (for version 9.2.4, obviously).

Comment: For postgres.app 9.3, they seem to have re-arranged the directories. I tried: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/createuser -s postgres, but this generated the same eror message: "createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist"

Comment: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/createuser -s postgres` ran correctly for me.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me is following the steps here http://www.mikeball.us/blog/setting-up-postgres-with-homebrew/ then running createuser -s postgres like you suggested. Thanks! It took me a whole day to get it to work.

Comment: With 9.4.1.0 I'm not seeing a createuser command.  However, as another comment says, it *does* create a user, it's just named after your username.  So if you try to open psql, then copy the command in the terminal and add `--user $USER` it will open up.  Then you can run the command `create user postgres with superuser`

Comment: I give up with this .app thing, gonna try brew

Comment: to get your version of pg, run `psql --version` in the terminal.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running ... this can help figure out which version you're using with homebrew

Comment: don't install postgres.app, it just confuses things later if you try to move away

Comment: @RogerLipscombe if you run `brew link postgresql` after the installation, there's no need to append the whole path to `createuser`, a simple `createuser -s postgres` will work great

Comment: `createuser -s postgres` worked for me. I installed postgres with Homebrew

Comment: it was `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@11/11.9/bin/createuser -s postgres` for me

Answer (score 160):

**And if you are here in 2024 :) and wondering what works with the latest Postgres on the latest macOS (macOS Monterey )**

**follow this:**

```
brew install postgresql
createuser -s postgres
brew services restart postgresql
```

Note: In case you are using a dockerized instance make sure to first set the variables so you can connect to that instance: export PGUSER="youruser" export PGHOST="127.0.0.1" export PGPASSWORD="yourpassword.

Thanks, @NicolasZ for the comment regarding dockerized instance.

Comment: that worked nicely running on Monterey.

Comment: Thanks!, i uninstall postgres and then i did what you say, it worked!

Comment: thank you very much! 

I just upgraded to mac OS v13 Ventura today and my postgres stopped working. I had to uninstall and reinstall it via `brew` (somehow upgrading it wasn't enough) and follow your suggestions. 

the `/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres` command mentioned in other answers also didn't work.

Comment: IN case you are using a dockerized instance make sure to first set the variables so you can  connect to that instance:
export PGUSER="youruser"
export PGHOST="127.0.0.1"
export PGPASSWORD="yourpassword"

Comment: Thank your this! Worked like a charm. Brew instructions should call this out.

Answer (score 95):

```
createuser postgres --interactive
```

or make a superuser postgresl just with

```
createuser postgres -s
```

Comment: Cool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist/46951367#46951367

Comment: I found this answer useful when my pgadmin kept on asking for postgres user and I dint have postgres role to begin with, this command created it, I added the autogenerated pw into my pgadmin and problem solved!

Comment: This works for me.. but this way: "create user postgres"

Answer (score 61):

This happens when you run `initdb` with a user whose ID is not `postgres`, without specifying the `postgres` username with `--username=postgres` or `-U postgres`.

The database cluster is then created with the system's user account that you used to run initdb, and it is given superuser permissions.

To fix it, simply create a new user named `postgres` with the option `--superuser` using the `createuser` utility that comes with Postgres.  The utility can be found in the Postgres' `bin` directory.  e.g.

```html
createuser --superuser postgres
```

If you have a custom hostname or port then be sure to [set the appropriate options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html).

Don't forget to delete the other user account that was created for you by initdb.

Comment: This is the exact explanation I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

If you installed postgres from brew, run this in your terminal :

```
/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this. This worked for me while setting up a server in pgAdmin 4.

Comment: For me the path was different ```/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/createuser -s postgres```

Answer (score 24):

**First** you need create a user:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
```

**After** you create a database:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb $USER
```

**Change** `$USER` to your system username.

*You can see the the complete solution [here](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-install-postgres-for-linux).*

Comment: I was receiving this error: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "jose.mateus" does not exist

None of the above worked for me, in case you are getting the same error as me, this option here helps

Answer (score 23):

I needed to unset `$PGUSER`:

```
$ unset PGUSER
$ createuser -s postgres
```

Answer (score 18):

If you installed postgres from Brew and are using an **Apple Silicon (M1) mac**, run this in your terminal:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

If you're using an **Intel (x86) mac**, run this in your terminal:

```
/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

Comment: ```/usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/bin/createuser -s postgres``` for postgres 14

Answer (score 17):

For me, this code worked:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

it came from here:
http://talk.growstuff.org/t/fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist/216/4

Comment: Does it mean this new posgres user won't have a password?

Answer (score 9):

Running this on the command line should fix it

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/createdb <Mac OSX Username Here>`

Comment: This works for me in MacOS 11.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This [article](https://gist.github.com/ibraheem4/ce5ccd3e4d7a65589ce84f2a3b7c23a3) helped me to solve same issue `psql: FATAL: role “postgres” does not exist`.

I am using mac, so I entered this command in terminal:

`createuser -s postgres`

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

We have a db named `postgres` after `brew install postgresql` and `brew services start postgresql`. So we can open psql like this by default.

```
psql postgres
```

And then we can add users with any name like this in that psql console.

```
CREATE USER postgres
```

And if we want a super user, then we can add `SUPERUSER` at the end.

Comment: Good instruction. 'psql postgres' is connecting the postgres database(default) within the current user

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

createuser -s postgres

note: I'm using mac catalina

Answer (score 8):

If you're using docker, make sure you're NOT using `POSTGRES_USER=something_else`, as this variable is used by the standard image to know the name of the PostgreSQL admin user (default as `postgres`).

In my case, I was using this variable with the intent to set another user to my specific database, but it ended up of course changing the main PostgreSQL user.

Answer (score 6):

For m1 chips, if you have not installed postgresql package by homebrew, install it in terminal with:

```
brew install postgre
```

then create a username manually by:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/createuser -s <username>
```

your error is probably fixed; but if you occur the error

> FATAL:  database "databasename" does not exist

then you have to create your database manually by:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/createdb -U <username>  <databasename>
```

Answer (score 4):

Dropping the `postgres` database doesn't really matter. This database is initially empty and its purpose is simply for the `postgres` user to have a kind of "home" to connect to, should it need one.

Still you may recreate it with the SQL command `CREATE DATABASE postgres;`

Note that the tutorial mentioned in the question is not written with `postgres.app` in mind.
Contrary to PostgreSQL for Unix in general, `postgres.app` tries to look like a normal application as opposed to a service that would be run by a dedicated `postgres` user having different privileges than your normal user. `postgres.app` is run and managed by your own account.

So instead of this command: `sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres`, it would be more in the spirit of postgres.app to just issue: `psql`, which automatically connects to a database matching your users's name, and with a db account of the same name that happens to be superuser, so it can do anything permissions-wise.

Comment: Okay. But why do I get an error `ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database` when I try to delete the user db? 

So is it not a good practice to use this postgres.app?

Comment: You cannot drop a db while connected to it. why would you want to delete it, anyway? It's here for your convenience.

Comment: I just wanted to see if I could. So it's like a default database correct when I boot up my psql and postgres.app?

Now what about the access privileges? I am not able to set them anymore? I see that template0  and template1 has access privileges

Comment: @user805981 `Postgres.app` is for testing and development purposes; it's a PostgreSQL package from Heroku that's designed to make it easier for Mac users developing with Ruby on Rails to test with PostgreSQL instead of the default SQLite. Rails uses tended to test with SQLite and deploy to PostgreSQL which caused all sorts of problems, so Heroku tried to make it easier to test on PostgreSQL too. `Postgres.app` is fine for testing, but I wouldn't consider using it for production or real data, that's just not what it's for.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only one that fixed it for me :

```
createuser -s -U $USER
```

Comment: This makes the current user a system superuser rather than just a postgres superuser. I would say this would be generally a bad idea as it circumvents the usual security policies. You should user `sudo` to gain temporary superuser privileges.

Answer (score 4):

For what it is worth, i have ubuntu and many packages installed and it went in conflict with it.

For me the right answer was:

```
sudo -i -u postgres-xc
psql
```

Answer (score 4):

I've faced similar problem today, actually i was not sure what was the username. Here is the 2 thing, if you are under enterprise and don't have system admin access the `postgres` will create your enterprise username as the `postgres` admin username. If you install through `Homebrew` it will definitely happening. In that case simply run your psql service with brew and do an echo of the username

`brew services start postgresql`

then

`echo $USER`

You will see your username of the postgres user.

Comment: damn. this actually worked. Thanks

Comment: This also worked for me on M1 Macbook... the postgres user was the username of my logged in account

Answer (score 3):

With a new mac (M1) and latest postgres (14.0) installed via homebrew, nothing helped me from this topic, but i just reinstalled postgres and it helped:

```sh
brew services stop postgresql
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/*
brew reinstall postgresql
initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /opt/homebrew/var/postgres
brew services restart postgresql
```

So, it's a miracle or something like that...

Then just:

```sh
psql -d postgres
```

Comment: Btw, i installed postgres earlier, but not used about 2 weeks, may be it was a bug or something else and it was fixed, i have no idea, but it works

Comment: You should not use that as you will install a random version of postgresql (most likely latest available on brew)

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, executing

```
createuser -s postgres
```

in a terminal worked.

Answer (score 3):

### My System

- Machine: M2 Macbook Pro
- macOS: Ventura 13.4.1
- Postgres Version: 15.3 (`postgres --version`)
- Installation Method: Homebrew

### My Solution

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a postgres user via the following command. Please note your postgres location and createuser utility may vary based on your system and/or installation method:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing this problem right after running a docker container try destroying the container and recreating it. That solved it for me:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

This should recreate the db with `postgresuser` as default user

Answer (score 2):

If you are a MAC (M1) user and installed the Postgres using HomeBrew then follow these steps:

1. Check your Postgres location using `which psql`
2. then run the command `/opt/homebrew/bin/createuser -s postgres` if the output for the first command is `/opt/homebrew/bin/psql`

The idea is to create a user named 'postgres' using the Postgres installation location. So you may need to change the command based on the location of your Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

#### Context

I am adding an answer for a case I have not seen here, which is an edge case if you have multiple users on the same machine and the user who is trying to use postgres services is not the user who installed postgres on the machine.

#### What I have tried

Among other similar commands, for me all these commands failed:

```bash
createuser -s [your username]
# createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "[your username]" does not exist
```

```bash
createuser -s postgres
# createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "[your username]" does not exist
```

```bash
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser [your username]
# sudo: unknown user: postgres
# sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

```bash
psql -U postgres
# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

#### Reason

The reason is because neither `postgres` role nor `[your username]` (aka whoami on your command line) are in postgres.

#### Solution

In such edge case I had to first login with the user who installed postgres:

```bash
sudo su - [username that installed postgres]
```

And then create a role for my new user:

```
createuser -s [your username]
```

Comment: it is amazing how my Stackoverflow answer comes in handy to myself exactly one year later and boom!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your terminal. Make sure that you're out of the postgres shell and your postgresql is running in the terminal.
Now run the following command in your terminal :

```js
createuser -s postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I only needed to create that user in the database I was restoring:

```
CREATE ROLE postgres;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu system, I purged the PostgreSQL and re-installed it. All the databases are restored.
This solved the problem for me.

Advice - Take the backup of the databases to be on the safer side.

Answer (score 1):

For m1 chips and homebrew version 3.4.9, the `createuser` is moved inside Cellar of the particular package.
This worked for me
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/bin/createuser -s postgres`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  that sudo is needed here because psql -l returns a list of databases.  This tells me that initdb was run under the user's current user, not under the postgres user.

You can just:

```
psql
```

And continue the tutorial.

I would suggest A.H's general points of creating the postgres user and db because many applications may expect this to exist.

A brief explanation:

PostgreSQL will not run with administrative access to the operating system.  Instead it runs with an ordinary user, and in order to support peer authentication (asking the OS who is trying to connect) it creates a user and db with the user that runs the initialization process.  In this case it was your normal user.

Comment: clears few important distinction in postgres. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I became stuck on this issue having executed `brew services stop postgresql` the day prior. 
 The day following: `brew services start postgresql` would not work. This is because as is shown when you install using homebrew. postgresql uses a launchd ... which loads when your computer is powered on. 
 resolution:
`brew services start postgresql` 
 Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The `\du` command return:

> Role name = `postgres@implicit_files`

And that command `postgres=# \password postgres` return error:

> ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist.

But that `postgres=# \password postgres@implicit_files` run fine.

Also after  `sudo -u postgres createuser -s postgres` the first variant also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
psql -U debug -d dashboard_3
```

I had to specify the username and database name using the `postgres:14` Docker container's terminal to be able to `psql` into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing psql error: FATAL: role “postgres” does not exist

1 - Install postgresql

> **brew install postgresql**

2 - Start postgresql

> **brew services start postgresql**

When running the command to access postgresql:

> **psql -U postgres**

And the error is thrown: "psql: FATAL: role “postgres” does not exist"

To correct:

> **/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql//bin/createuser -s postgres**

or

> **/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres**

This way the postgresql user is created and you can have access.

- if the above code doesn't work you can try this one below

> **`sudo su postgres createuser -s postgres -U <your-os-username>`**