# starting postgres server on Mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am having this issue third or forth time where after restarting my Mac (Yosemite and same thing with previous OSX version) postgres server doesn't start. I had installed my postgres following [this](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/three-battle-tested-ways-to-install-postgresql) link. Any idea why this consistently occurs after every restart?

typing `psql` it gives

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just fixed this on my mac. I used homebrew to install postgres. These are the steps I took to get up and running again.

First check the status of the postgresql service:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
```

if you see this `pg_ctl: no server running`, unload the launch agent:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

then move your existing postgres data (move rather than delete - cheap insurance):

```
mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres-deletemewhenitsallgood
```

then initialize your postgres database:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

then load your launch agent:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

OR start it:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Now check the status again:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
```

if you see something like this, you are good to go.

```
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 61295)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/bin/postgres "-D" "/usr/local/var/postgres"
```

Then you can go into your postgres database:

```
psql -d postgres
```

Also after that you need to add postgress Role.
[To Resolve missing postgres Role error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

Comment: This sequence of commands assumes that the asker is OK to loose all the database data and restart from scratch, which was never mentioned in the question.

Comment: The OP said after installing it and restarting several times they could not connect because of the error. If there is data that needs to be saved it is still on the filesystem and can be recovered.

Comment: @m79lkm AWESOMEEEE!! It worked perfectly for me after being stuck on this issue for 2 days. Keep up the good work champ!

Comment: Although this answer helped me, it would be interesting to understand if there is a duplication of psql installations, one for brew and other for osx. I'm lost in this aspect.

Comment: What were the events before you saw this problem? This is such a regular occurrence to me, I have SO threads bookmarked. Why do I have to move around the entire Postgres datastore just to restart my server? Any ideas on what caused this or how to prevent it? I guess for me, I updated Mac (which took my computer HOSTAGE as Apple tends to do).

Answer (score 5):

**To start postgres server on mac:**

install postgres with brew

```
brew install postgres
```

ensure you have permissions for */usr/local/postgres*

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

then init the db:

`initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`

To have `launchd` start postgresql at login:

`ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

To load postgresql:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

To check your version:

`psql --version`

And to access postgres

`psql -d postgres`

Comment: `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents` got it working for me. Thanks