# Not allowed do anything in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I've seen plenty of answers across the internet saying that to combat the

```
psql:FATAL: role <username> does not exist
```

one must use the `createuser` command, but about a dozen different attempts with that command have only yielded a similar error message.

I've installed PostgreSQL using Ubuntu 15.04's `sudo apt-get install postgresql`, but PostgreSQL permits to do absolutely nothing.

Do I need to install some dependencies or something?

Comment: Here are some links that I unsuccessfully consulted:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist]
[http://postgresql.nabble.com/role-does-not-exist-td5730246.html]
[http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/*bsd-17/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist-error-935394/]

Comment: change to the postgres user. from the command line `su - postgres`

Comment: just tried that; it asked for a password, and when I entered my system password, it failed to authenticate :(

Comment: Then you need to use `sudo` before the command.

Comment: Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing these actions as the `postgres` user:

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
```

---

The PostgreSQL installation makes a `postgres` user which runs the PostgreSQL service. It is essentially the superuser of your database. In most cases, you don't know the password for this user but any superuser of a system can log in to other accounts.