# PostgreSQL + IntelliJ : FATAL : role xxx doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I am able to connect with psql and do what I want, not in IntelliJ.

```
PostgreSQL version : postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
IntelliJ version : 2016.3.1
```

IntelliJ configuration :

```
URL : jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
User : sample
Pwd : sample
```

Test connection : Successful

So, I connect (red square appears) and then try a simple query :

```
select 1;
```

And I got the error  :

```
FATAL : role 'xxx' doesn't exist`
```

Why IntelliJ doesn't use the role specified in my configuration and want to use my personal login ?? Whatever I use as role, still got the same error.

**Note**: If I add my system username as role it works, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: That did it for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist

Comment: No It is not the same case. I already have the postgres user, and I can do exactly what I want in CLI. I think it is just an IntelliJ configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the LOGIN role attribute fix the problem :

```
ALTER ROLE sample LOGIN
```

The documenation states :

> Only roles that have the LOGIN attribute can be used as the initial
>   role name for a database connection

However, I could connect in CLI and do what I want, as I could "connect"  in IntelliJ but not do query, without this attribute. More details about this behaviour are welcome.