# run bash script containing postgresql script failed

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have already create bash script containing sql script (postgresql), but failed.

owner the file : postgres:postgres with 777 (chmod), but when I execute with "./bash1.sh" error: psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

THE_DATABASE=epolicy
MY_TABLE=hpx_sms

psql ${THE_DATABASE} <<THE_END
  SELECT * FROM ${MY_TABLE};
THE_END
```

how to fix this problem? or any reference? thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

Comment: Are you able to access psql from the command line? You might want to find out the appropriate user to log-in the database. It is not a bash script issue, if you can fix this: `psql epolicy`, you can fix your bash script too.

Comment: thanks, problem solved, I execute with postgres user, not root or padmin