# Trying to load Postgres sample database dvdrental

Tags: sql, postgresql, terminal

I'm a newbie and new to Postgresql. I'm following a tutorial online and after downloading and extracting the `dvdrental.zip` into `dvdrental.tar` .  I changed directory to my postgres bin location. And tried to run

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental '/Users/macbookair/Downloads/dvdrental/dvdrental.tar'
```

But I got this error:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dvdrental" failed:
>   FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Meanwhile my `dvdrental` database has a `postgres` role.

Comment: Have you read, and tried, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first: you must create a database in SQL-Shell:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdvdrental;
```

look at first picture

[Creating New DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMcsM.jpg)

In the next step:

```
pg_restore --dbname=newdvdrental -U postgres --verbose C:\dvdrental\dvdrental.tar
```

look at second picture:

[Restoring dvdrental.tar to new database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE2em.jpg)

And by checking result in PgAdmin:

[checking result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG5Uw.jpg)