# Connecting to postgres as ubuntu standard user

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I want to connect to my postgresql when running my python program. The issue i face is that my username is *dave*, but i can only access my database with the user postgres on linux. This constellation never failed me on my mac, because i could start postgres from my "dave" user account. With linux (ubuntu) i can only connect to the database with psql, when switching my user with *sudo -su postgres to the *postgres* user.

How am i able to start my program from my user *dave* while accessing the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a user called `dave`:

- Log on using `sudo -u postgres`
- create database davedb;
- create user dave with encrypted password 'testing';
- grant all privileges on database davedb to dave;

Then, you can log in from your username itself like so:

```
psql dave davedb
--or--
psql -U dave -d davedb
```

If it asks you for your password, type it. You should be in then.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to connect to PostgreSQL from inside its docker container.

So I opened the terminal of the docker container:

```bash
docker exec -it deep-postgres bash
```

Then I changed the user to `postgres`:

```
su postgres
```

And then I started the client:

```
psql
```

It all should look like this:

```
deep@deep:~$ docker exec -it deep-postgres bash
root@7b02446de835:/# su postgres
postgres@7b02446de835:/$ psql
DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
psql (12.11 (Debian 12.11-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Then, if you need to be able to log in with another user, you can create database and user like this:

```sql
CREATE database db;
CREATE USER dave WITH encrypted password 'test';
GRANT ALL privileges ON database db TO dave;
```

Then `exit` from `psql` and login using another user:

```bash
psql -U dave -d db
```

It will look like this:

```
postgres@7b02446de835:/$ psql -U dave -d db
DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
psql (12.11 (Debian 12.11-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

db=>
```