# Building a database url to connect fastapi to my local postgresql database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am setting a fastAPI, and I have a postgresql database I want to connect it to. I am following a [this guide](https://www.tutlinks.com/fastapi-with-postgresql-crud-async/) to do so, and I am finding some errors when trying to set the DATABASE_URL.

My end goal is to perform a SQL query to such database, and then later, deploy the application to Heroku where I should connect it to the postgresql database stored there.

```
host_server = os.environ.get('host_server', 'localhost')
db_server_port = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('db_server_port', '5432')))
database_name = os.environ.get('nameofmydatabase', 'fastapi')
db_username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('myusername', 'postgres')))
db_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('mypassword123', 'secret')))
ssl_mode = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(os.environ.get('ssl_mode','prefer')))
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?sslmode={}'.format(db_username, db_password, host_server, db_server_port, database_name, ssl_mode)
```

With that configuration I am getting

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist

Comment: Verify that there is an environment variable named `myusername` that contains the appropriate user name.

Comment: @GordThompson it does exist for sure, I am using it to connect it on a ruby on rails application and is working fine