# SQLAlchemy Connection Error with Postgres SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psql

My Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(_name_)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:Admin123456%40@localhost/oklondon'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class london_companies(db.Model):
    
    tablename = 'london_companies'
    
    company_name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    employees = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    graduate_schemes = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)
    headquarters = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    companies = london_companies.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', companies=companies)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2023 19:13:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

- My actual password is Admin123456@,so I have changed the '@' symbol to %40
- My user has all the privileges:

[image]

Comment: Are these answers helpful: [psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

Comment: What command do you access your database?