# PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist and role "postgres@ does not exist

Tags: postgresql, macbookpro

I have installed postgres and when I run `psql` I am getting:

```
PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist
```

and also when I run p`sql -h localhost -U postgres` I get:

```
PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "postgres" does not exist
```

errors.

I have looked extensively at other questions here and in other locations such as:
[PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

[psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

I can't make progress with any of the solutions.

I am on a Mac M1 with Sonoma. I installed postgres with homebrew and I am on version 14.

psql --version returns:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Homebrew)
```

Is there anything else I can try seeing as I am encountering both errors.

`export` returns:

```
HOME=/Users/username
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew
INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
LOGNAME=username
MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man::
OLDPWD=/Users/username
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
PWD=/Users/username
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=username
```

If I run /opt/homebrew/bin/createuser -s postgres (for example) there is no change.

```
`ps ax | grep postgres` returns:

50147   ??  S      0:00.08 /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
50149   ??  Ss     0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer
50150   ??  Ss     0:00.05 postgres: background writer
50151   ??  Ss     0:00.03 postgres: walwriter
50152   ??  Ss     0:00.06 postgres: autovacuum launcher
50153   ??  Ss     0:00.08 postgres: stats collector
50154   ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: logical replication launcher
51978 s002  S+     0:00.00 grep postgres
```

`psql postgres` returns

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

`psql -d postgres -U username` and `psql -d postgres -U "username"` return:

`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist`

Comment: 1) You need to add the command you are using when the error occurs as text update to question. 2) Homebrew does not create the `postgres` role. Instead it uses the OS user name you installed it via as the default Postgres ownwr.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, I have updated my question. The OS user name is username as specified above. I can't add a role for username as there is no role postgres I believe.

Comment: Running `/opt/homebrew/bin/createuser -s postgres` makes no difference.

Comment: Try `psql postgres`.

Comment: I have moved the result of `psql postgres` and `ps ax | grep postgres` to the question.

Comment: What does `ps ax | grep postgres` return?

Comment: Try `psql -d postgres -U username` and if that does not work then  `psql -d postgres -U "username"`.

Comment: I don't know about homebrew, but usually at the end of installing a database server there are additional instructions to initialize it. Check the install log.

Comment: @Schwern. The server is running, both the `ps` output (`-D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14`) and `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist` confirm it. The issue is the user name the OP is connecting as is not found.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have update the question with the output of your last two requests.

Comment: 1) Where did you get Postgres from [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql@14#default) or [Homebrew Eisentraut](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql)? 2) Did you do the install as user other then the one you are trying to connect from?

Comment: homebrew. I did the install as the same user as I am trying to connect from.

Comment: Hmm, I am at loss as to how this could be happening. The only option I can offer at this time is to go here [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html) and follow the instructions here *Single-User Mode*.  You will need to shut down the  existing running cluster before you do this. Once you are in under single user mode do `select * from pg_user` to see what user is present.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run `postgres --single -D /usr/local/var/postgres` I get `FATAL:  database "username" does not exist' but maybe i am doing something else wrong.

Comment: I figured out something but I will come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: Where is `/usr/local/var/postgres` coming from? Your `ps ax` output showed the Postgres server running at `/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14`. In any case try `postgres --single -D <whatever PGDATA directory> postgres` to force it to connect to `postgres` database.

Comment: @atw It's clear the database is running, but it may not have been properly initizalized. Post-install you have to run initdb to create a database and role. Homebrew should have done this, but maybe it didn't, or perhaps it was run as a different user. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-initdb.html

Comment: @Schwern, *It's clear the database is running, but it may not have been properly initizalized.* is a contradiction in terms. If there where not a properly initialized cluster the server would not be running. Now I do buy the cluster creation as different user argument.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the PostgreSQL server, start it in single-user mode as described in the documentation and query `pg_user` to find the names of the database users.