# How to choose from - Multiple versions of PostgreSql on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I have version 9.5 installed .  For creating a local backup from Heroku i need version 9.6.1 as thats the one on Heroku - otherwise pg__dump fails with an error.

Ubuntu console dump below -

```
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ 
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 9.6.2
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ 
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ 
postgres@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ psql -c 'SELECT version();'
                                                     version                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ 
postgres@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$
```

UPDATE - As suggested --

```
~$ locate pg_dump
/etc/alternatives/pg_dump.1.gz
/etc/alternatives/pg_dumpall.1.gz
/usr/bin/pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/share/man/man1/pg_dump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pg_dumpall.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/man/man1/pg_dump.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/man/man1/pg_dumpall.1.gz
```

Further update , used pg_lsclusters :~

```
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ 
(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log       /postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
9.6 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log    /postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

(py27infoBOT) dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:~$

Comment: Need to clarify further :-

Comment: you question in subject does not correlate to body. Please edit the question

Comment: Need to clarify further --- have had version Postgres 9.5 on local machine . Have used the same for local Django app . Same app ported on Heroku. While backing up Heroku DB on local with - heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL ...etc . got an ....ERROR -- `heroku-cli: Pulling postgresql-shaped-51549 ---> localDB_infobot_7APR_1300
pg_dump: server version: 9.6.1; pg_dump version: 9.5.6
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)`
 Tried - upgrading my local 16.4 - to 9.6 with sudo apt get - but failed as seen below ---

Comment: Further did this - `$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main"
$ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add-` got a success prompt `OK`

Comment: Finally was able to download Postgres 9.6.2 -- got the following in console - `Creating new cluster 9.6/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
  locale en_IN
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5433
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up postgresql-contrib-9.6 (9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...`

Comment: update your question with results of either of `locate pg_dump` or `whereis pg_dump` or sudo find / -name pg_dump` or all

Comment: Further when i followed this question here - i got conflicting inputs , what do i do now ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running?rq=1

Comment: run `updatedb` and then `locate pg_dump` again. if result does not change - you did not install 9.6

Comment: Actually both were running - have stopped 9.5 now . Now 9.6 is running on - port 5433 , will figure out how to connect to same - thanks for your time and efforts you were really helpful - thanks @Vao Tsun

Answer (score 1):

Seems like i should document the solution that worked for me - I edited the .conf file for 9.6.2 to listen on port 5432 -

```
"config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf"
```

Current status as below -

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Further Update :~
Issue not resolved - now referring this very educative answer from user - Erwin Brandstetter , https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21006/how-to-run-specific-version-8-4-9-1-of-postgresql-pg-command-e-g-pg-dump/21007#21007 . Further question - How do i use the `$ pg_dump --cluster 9.6/main` , with the Heroku CLI command which is :- `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL localDB_infobot --app infobot-co-in` .

The standalone - `$ pg_dump --cluster 9.6/main` at local console results in - `another ERROR`

As of now - as a temporary solution , resorting to DB backup , download and local restore -

`heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user_name -d database_name latest.dump`