# Which is the Postgres version

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I have a doubt about my version of Postgres installed in my environment.

This is my os: `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`
In `/usr/` I can see: `pgsql-9.4/` folder.

But when I do: `select version();` I get:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.18 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
```

So, what version do I have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which version of PostgreSQL am I running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To determine the version of the database **server**, use `select version()` (from a connection to the database):

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                version                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit
```

To determine the version of the database **client**, use `psql --version` (from your shell command line):

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2
```

The server is where data is stored. The client is the software you use to connect to the server. They can be different versions.

Comment: Hi, I am getting these   with Select version() --> **PostgreSQL 11devel**. With psql --version ----> **psql (PostgreSQL) 11devel**  but when I do **postgres -V '---->' postgre 9.6.6** (why?).. Any Idea?

Comment: You likely have two different postgres installs, and a PATH that includes both directories. This is probably its own question, though, not a comment on a two year old post. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply check the version by this command: `psql --version`

Answer (score 0):

You may of course have more than one instance of Postgresql. Try this sql to show your current instance location in case there is more than one

```
SHOW data_directory;
```