# How to parse the correct version number?

Tags: linux, shell

The command below will return the corresponding strings

```
$ docker-compose exec postgres postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)
```

I am trying to get the postgresql version but when I tried, the Debian version and other numbers are included like

```
$ pg_version=$(docker-compose exec postgres postgres --version | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')
10.410.42.901
```

I am wondering how to get the `10.4` only

Comment: You could hack it at spaces etc. ... but I'd use one of the other methods (like SHOW server_version): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running

Comment: It still showed `10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `sed` as followed would help,

```
sed -E 's/.*PostgreSQL[^0-9.]+([0-9.]*).*/\1/'
```

`\1` would only match to the version number right behind "PostgreSQL".

Answer (score 2):

- `awk -v RS=" " '/^[0-9.]+$/{print; exit}'`
- `grep -oE '[.0-9]+' | head -1`
- `tr ' ' '\n' | grep -oE -m 1 '[.0-9]+'`
- `sed 's|^[^0-9.]*\([0-9.]\+\).*|\1|'`

Answer (score 1):

`pg_version=$(docker-compose exec postgres postgres -V | grep -oE '[.0-9]+' | head -1)`

Comment: `10.4 10.4`. This value returned. How to return only one 10.4?

Comment: Since it finds the version two times, put `head -1` to print first one.

Comment: @Sumit : I think the egrep pattern `[.0-9]+` would be sufficient in this case. BTW, it's better to write it as `grep -oE`, since `egrep` is deprecated.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` with something like this:

```
$ grep -oP "PostgreSQL.\s\K.+?(?=\s)"
```

For example:

```
$ echo "postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)" | grep -oP "SQL.\s\K.+?(?=\s)"
10.4
```

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left `*SQL)<space>` before it and return only the right part `.+?(?=\s)` until and space `\s` is found.