# Why does `pg_config --version` give a different version than `select version();` does?

Tags: postgresql, nixos

I am attempting to identify what version of postgres server I have installed, and noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733719/which-version-of-postgresql-am-i-running) on that.

The first answer there says to run `SELECT version();` (in postgres), the second answer says to run `pg_config --version` (in the terminal). Somehow I get different versions when running each of these commands.

In Postgres:

```
=> select version();
                                      version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.12 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 5.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

In the terminal:

```
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 9.6.2
```

Why are different version numbers reported when running these two commands?

My machine is running NixOS.

Comment: Did you install both versions? Maybe is in your path the other pg_config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abdel P. suggested, it turned out that I had both a global and a user-level postgres installed.

I uninstalled the user-level version and now both show version 9.4.12.