# OSX: How to change user password when account was created without one?

Tags: postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

When I installed the PostgreSQL database server on my Mac, I created the "postgres" account so that it wouldn't have a password:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres Password \*
```

I thought this would be a good security precaution to take.  However, it also prevents me from logging in via the su command so that I can use psql to administer the database:

```
su - postgres    # <- prompts me for password
```

I've tried to change the postgres password using the "passwd" and "dscl . -passwd /Users/postgres" commands but they always prompt me for the old password.  How do I set the password in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: This might belong on Super User... if your question gets closed, don't fret. Just go there.

Comment: [Probably the same solution as here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo su - postgres` instead. Enter the sudo password, and you'll be postgres.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still prompts me for a password.

Comment: Yes, it prompts for the admin user's password (because of the `sudo` command). It's the one you need to enter when you install software on your Mac.