# Unable To Run PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

Whenever I try to run 'psql' I receieve the following error message:

```
ahcarpenter@ubuntu:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "ahcarpenter" does not exist
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: See [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role “username” does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

That happens because

```
$ psql
```

is equivalent to

```
$ psql ahcarpenter -U ahcarpenter
```

As that user does not exist enter as user postgres

```
$ psql -U postgres
```

Once inside create the user and the database "ahcarpenter".

```
create user ahcarpenter;
create database ahcarpenter with owner ahcarpenter;
```

exit

```
\q
```

Reenter

```
$ psql
```

Comment: So after trying 'psql -U postgres' I get the following: 'psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"'.

Comment: @Drew - taking your other questions into account, you're going to have to sit down for an hour or so and at least skim the manuals and a tutorial. You're not going to get anywhere until you have at least a basic understanding of some of the terms used.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Do you by any chance know how to resolve the error of which I wrote above?

Comment: Yes - either run as the required user, or correct your pg_hba.conf to not require peer auth. Now you can either skim the manuals and read a tutorial to find out all the details, or I can tell you and you can come back in 5 minutes when you get stuck again.

Comment: So I edited my pg_hba.conf file to include the following line:

local ahcarpenter ahcarpenter

After trying to run 'psql' again, I received the following error: "psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "ahcarpenter", database "ahcarpenter", SSL off"

Comment: @Drew Did you reload or restart the server?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I'm not sure. I exited out of the terminal window and then reopened it. Would that cause the server to be reloaded/restarted the next time I ran 'psql'?

Comment: @Drew No. What is the OS?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Ubuntu

Comment: @Drew If it were a Redhat derivated OS I would do `service postgresql reload` Try that. If it does not work ask an Ubuntu guru how to reload a service.