# psql - Role root does not exist

Tags: php, bash, postgresql

I build a bash command in a PHP script. The built command is such as :

```
su postgres -c "for tbl in `psql -qAt -c \"select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';\" demodoo` ;do  psql -c \"alter table $tbl owner to postgres\" demodoo ;done "
```

When I try to run this command in a shell, I get this error :

```
 psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Why is this occuring, whereas i execute the command under postgres user ?

Thanks 
Cheers,

**EDIT**
I change the command to

```
sudo -u postgres for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" demodoo` ;do  psql -c "alter table $tbl owner to postgres" demodoo ;done
```

but now I get another error which I can't understand the origin :

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Comment: check this link : http://serverfault.com/questions/601140/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-su-postgres-and-sudo-u-postgres

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question after reading the post, but I get an error

Comment: This link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist

Answer (score 10):

try:

`sudo -u postgres psql`

`>` `CREATE USER root WITH SUPERUSER;`

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly get it working, by saving the content of the command

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" demodoo` ;do  psql -c "alter table $tbl owner to postgres" demodoo ;done
```

in a file `myfile.sh`, then call the file as follow :

```
sudo -u postgres /bin/bash myfile.sh
```

Thank you for your help