# psql fatal role does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu and I'm not used to it yet. I had several problems connecting PostgreSQL with pgadmin3.

I tried to follow several tutorials to create a localhost server which I can use in pgadmin3. I didn't really hit the mark and I think I made it worse by installing, uninstalling, installing, uninstalling, trying answers I found... At this point I'm not sure my PostgreSQL is clean. It could be possible that I have two PostgreSQL installed, once again, I'm not sure. I tried to uninstall it but I had an error which basically said PostgreSQL wasn't in sudo.

The thing is I now have this error running psql in the console:

```
$psql
psql: FATAL: role "user" does not exist
```

I can't find the `pg_hba.conf` and at this point I'm too afraid to make things even worse by trying following any other posts.

How could I make this work?

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` is irrelevant here. You are trying to connect with the username `user` - but that account/username/role does not exists. You need to specify an existing database user using the `-U` switch when starting `psql`

Comment: Since the error message comes from psql, you are already connected to the DBMS, No need to mess with pg_hba.conf. As the message says: the user name "user" does not exist. BTW: `user` is a terrible name for a user. Would you call your child `child` ?

Comment: I wans't clear but instead of user, that's the name of my session that is written. I'll try all that tonight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your pg_hba.conf seems fine.

Usually, the database will run as the postgres user (check `ps aux | grep postgres` to find out the username postgres is running under).

Log in as that user, for example `sudo su - postgres`, then create a user matching your normal Ubuntu user account (`createuser username`), and finally create a database with that same name and set the owner (`-O`) to that database user, like this: `createdb -O username username`).

That should make calling `psql` work, and pgadmin - as long as you start it as your default user, username - should work as well.

Edit: By default, `psql` will use your Linux username as default value for both the database-username and the database-name. You can override the username by using `-U someotherusername`, and connect to a different database by adding that DB name to the command line, such as `psql someotherdbname`. You might also find `psql -l` useful for listing the existing databases.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a database for that user. The database can be specified when starting psql: `psql db_name`

Comment: I've added an edit to clarify that. In most cases though, you will want calling `psql` with no parameters to "just work", so that's what my answer focussed on.

Comment: Hi,

Thank's for your answers,

Comment: Sorry for double post

Hi,

Thank's for your help, it's fine for postgres, now. Still, I cannot manage to connect to pgadmin3, it seems that the server version is not supported by pgadmin3 but that's another topic...

Anyway, thank's again.

Comment: `sudo su - postgres` 
------ `createuser jonny`
-------- `createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "jonny" already exists` ---------
`exit; whoami;` ------- `jonny` ---------- `psql` ----------  `FATAL:  role "jonny" does not exist`

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser user
```

may help you to create a new user with all the privileges of postgres

Comment: logged in $ sudo su - postgres, then connected to $ psql
psql (9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#

Answer (score 4):

Use the postgres user:

```
sudo su postgres
```

and then use psql.

If you still face problems check this link: [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 this works for fine

pg_restore --format=c --verbose --no-owner --no-privileges --dbname=MYDB --username=postgres --no-password --jobs=8 F:/MYBK.backup

--username=(role) and --no-password are necesaries

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a bit question old if you're facing this on windows, simply delete Postgres `data` directory and re-initialize Postgres data by running `initdb /data`