# Checking list of psql roles without being able to type psql

Tags: postgresql

I know I have psql installed on my computer. However, no matter what user I use, postgres, my username or root, I keep getting a FATAL: role does not exist. Now, I was wondering if I could see a list of roles that I try seeing as how I can't type psql to go to the database itself.

Comment: check role for postgres process `ps aux | grep postgres` and try  to psql using it. detailed answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213929/psql-fatal-role-does-not-exist)

Comment: Remember that psql is the default command-line client program and basically independent of your PostgreSQL server installation. There is no such thing as a "psql role". The name of the RDBMS is "PostgreSQL" or "postgres" for short. Or "pg" for super-short. Never "psql", to avoid confusion. Please clarify your question.