# "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted

Tags: postgresql, sudo, privileges

When I try to start postgresql I get an error:

```
postgres
```

> postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
>   You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the
>   PGDATA environment variable.

So then I try to set my config file:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And I get the following error:

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": Permission denied

Hmm okay. Next, I try to perform that same action as an admin:

```
 sudo postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And I receive the following error:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
>   The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
>   possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for more
>   information on how to properly start the server.

I googled around for that error message but cannot find a solution.
Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Comment: Assuming you are in postgres bin folder , you can do 'sudo -u postgres pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/'

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your command does not do what you think it does. To run something as **system user** `postgres`:

```
 sudo -u postgres command
```

To run the **command** (also named `postgres`!):

```
sudo -u postgres postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Your command does the opposite:

```
sudo postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

It runs the program `postgres` as the superuser `root` (`sudo` without `-u` switch), and Postgres does not allow to be run with superuser privileges for security reasons. Hence the error message.

If you are going to run a couple of commands as system user `postgres`, change the user with:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

... and `exit` when you are done.

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

If you see this error message while operating as system user `postgres`, then something is wrong with permissions on the file or one of the containing directories.

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
> /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf

Consider [instruction in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html).
Also consider the wrapper [`pg_ctl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) - or [`pg_ctlcluster`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) in Debian-based distributions.
And know the difference between [`su`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/su) and [`sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo). Related:

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677#11919677)

Comment: How to force Postgres to run as root if I really need this under docker?

Comment: @Odysseus: You can't. The server process (`postgres`) actively refuses to be run by the `root` user. For sanity.

Answer (score 73):

For those trying to run custom command using the official docker image, use the following command. `docker-entrypoint.sh` handles switching the user and handling other permissions.

```
docker-entrypoint.sh -c 'shared_buffers=256MB' -c 'max_connections=200'
```

Comment: ok, firstly `docker exec <container_id> -it bash`, then type the command in this answer.

Comment: You just saved me a few hours of work, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The answer of Muthukumar is the best !! After all day searching by the more simple way of change my Alpine Postgres deployment in Kubernetes, I found this simple answer.

There is my complete description. Enjoy it !!

First I need to create/define a ConfigMap with correct values. Save in the file "custom-postgresql.conf":

```
# DB Version: 12
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: oltp
# Total Memory (RAM): 16 GB
# CPUs num: 4
# Connections num: 9999
# Data Storage: ssd
# https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/
# 2020-10-29
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 9999
shared_buffers = 4GB
effective_cache_size = 12GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 209kB
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

Create the Config/Map:

```
kubectl create configmap custom-postgresql-conf --from-file=custom-postgresql.conf
```

> Please, take care that the values in custom settings are defined
> according to the Pod resources, mainly by memory and CPU assignments.

There is the manifest (postgres.yml):

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 128Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: postgres
    tier: core
  ports:
    - name: port-5432-tcp
      port: 5432

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
      tier: core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
        tier: core
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
        - name: postgresql-conf
          configMap:
            name: postgresql-conf
            items:
              - key: custom-postgresql.conf
                path: postgresql.conf
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12-alpine
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 128Mi
              cpu: 600m
            limits:
              memory: 16Gi
              cpu: 1500m
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - "psql"
                - "-w"
                - "-U"
                - "postgres"
                - "-d"
                - "postgres"
                - "-c"
                - "SELECT 1"
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - "psql"
                - "-w"
                - "postgres"
                - "-U"
                - "postgres"
                - "-d"
                - "postgres"
                - "-c"
                - "SELECT 1"
            initialDelaySeconds: 45
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          # this was the problem !!!
          # I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311825/root-execution-of-the-postgresql-server-is-not-permitted
          command: [ "docker-entrypoint.sh", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf" ]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgresql
            - name: postgresql-conf
              mountPath: /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
              subPath: postgresql.conf
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: etldatasore-username
                  key: ETLDATASTORE__USERNAME
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: etldatasore-database
                  key: ETLDATASTORE__DATABASE
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: etldatasore-password
                  key: ETLDATASTORE__PASSWORD
```

You can apply with

```
kubectl apply -f postgres.yml
```

Go to your pod and check for applied settings:

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl exec -it postgres-548f997646-6vzv2 bash

bash-5.0# su - postgres
postgres-548f997646-6vzv2:~$ psql

postgres=# show config_file;
           config_file
---------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

postgres=#

# if you want to check all custom settings, do
postgres=# SHOW ALL;
```

Thank you [Muthukumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515774/muthukumar) !!

Please, try yourself, validate, and share !!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in 2 areas : docker-compose & kubernetes deployment.

To solve it on docker-compose it was enough to edit the command arg :

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    command: postgres -c max_connections=200
```

For the kubernetes deployment, I had to pass the configuration that we want to set (`max_connection`) as the `args` in the deployment, e.g :

```
args: ["-c", "max_connections=200"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Terminal returns postgres command not found.

Unable to update postgresql

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).