# Cannot set postgres config file in container deployed in Azure Container Instances

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I am currently testing Azure Container Instances and want to deploy a multi-container project set up with docker compose. However, I already struggle setting up only a single postgres container with my custom config file as part of docker compose.

The **Dockerfile** looks as follows:

```
FROM postgres:14
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/
COPY ./db-postgres/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
COPY ./db-postgres/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

The **docker compose YAML** is:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres-acr
    image: <containerregistry>.azurecr.io/postgres:dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile_postgres
    command: postgres -c 'config_file=etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: <dbname>
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <userpassword>
    user: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

On my local windows based machine this setup works fine with Docker Desktop and WSL2. However, if I deploy this container in Azure Container Instances, I continue to receive the following error:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted. The server
> must be started under a nunprivileged user ID to prevent possible
> system security comprise.

According to several other posts on Stackoverflow (e.g. ["root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311825/root-execution-of-the-postgresql-server-is-not-permitted)) this indicates that the command `postgres -c 'config_file=etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'` is executed via root, but should instead be executed by the postgres user. I tried to make sure that it is executed by the postgres user, by setting the user property in the service definition, but the problem persists.

I am confused what I am missing and why the given setup works fine on my local machine, but fails in Azure Container Instances.

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: add `USER postgress` in Dockerfile and verify.