# Rails and PostgreSQL - Role when executing a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, roles, rails-migrations

I have successfully imported a PostgreSQL dump and linked it with my Rails application.

When trying to run rails migrations I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist

Where "username" is my account name. I have the following configuration in the database.yml file:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: name_of_the_db
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: password
  template: template0
```

I would like to run the migrations with the *postgres* user, not creating a new  role like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist).

Why is *username* being used as the role for the migrations? I thought the user defined in the database.yml would be used.

How can I config *postgres* instead?

Edit:

I've made the following changes to my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                password

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     password
```

But I've only been able to change the way the user authenticates, not which user is used on the migrations. I can't see how to change that in this file.

Comment: Your problem is called [peer authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER).

Comment: Have you made the necessary changes to you pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I'm new to PostgreSQL and didn't know about this. I'll have a look at it.