# psql: FATAL: role "vagrant" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, vagrant

I have been trying to set up vagrant but I am getting this error.
I will list out my installation method. Please suggest changes where you feel they are needed.

-Installed virtual box
`sudo apt-get install virtual box`

-Downloaded .deb package from vagrant website

-Installed it using
 `sudo dpkg -i (package_name)`

-then I selected the vagrant folder in the fullstack folder and
`vagrant up`
`vagrant ssh`

then I did :
`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32: cd /vagrant/forum
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$ sudo apt-get install postgres-xc-client`

Then finally:
`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist`

Comment: Sure, you haven't set up a Postgres role that corresponds to your current user (which is `vagrant`).  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/user-manag.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Comment: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to change to the `postgres` user and give vagrant superuser access.

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser vagrant -s
exit  # exit from postgres user back into vagrant
```

You can do everything with with vagrant now.

Comment: If provisioning a bash file script for installing the host, the following seems to work better when used inside the script:

`sudo -u postgres createuser vagrant -s && sudo -u postgres createdb vagrant`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly for me. For a novice like me, maybe it will help to mention that the above commands need to be entered after you have ssh (ed) into your Linux/ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because there is no role specified in postgres. When there is no role specified, it tries to use the username of the account as the default role and hence your error. So, now, you could either create a role in postgres for the vagrant user or just use the postgres user itself.
So, first, login with the postgres user:

```
psql -U postgres
```

then, create a role for the user vagrant

```
CREATE ROLE vagrant LOGIN;
```

In case, if you want it with a password, use:

```
CREATE USER vagrant WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

or

```
CREATE ROLE vagrant WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

CREATE USER is the same as CREATE ROLE with the exception that USER implies LOGIN.

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createrole.html)

Comment: `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/$ psql -U postgres  
                                                                                                                   psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/$ 
`

Comment: try  'sudo service postgres restart'

Comment: `postgres: unrecognized service`

Comment: sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib;

and then repeat the steps in the answer. Looks like a postgres installation issue.

Comment: After I run `psql -U postgres` it gives this error:                                `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to postgresql using **vagrant** user.  In this case, postgresql y looking for the corresponding **vagrant** role (if not specified, the default role for a user is it's username).  However, looks like there is no such role created.

You can create the role, or try for example a login using the **postgres** user:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$ psql -U postgres
```

You can also specify the databasename you want to connect to:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$ psql -U postgres -d DATABASENAME
```

Comment: `-bash: vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/forum$: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's the path specified in the question.  Simply try to type **psql** the command: psql -U postgres -d DATABASENAME

Answer (score 0):

1. First exit the vagrant prompt

   exit
2. Halt the vagrant instance

   vagrant halt
3. Destroy the vagrant instance

   vagrant destroy
4. Create a new instance

   vagrant up

This might solve it. It atleast did for me.(Tried it)

Comment: This feels a bit too much like "turn it off and turn it back on again" . I get that that often works, but a useful answer really should help with understanding the problem