# when I try to do rake db:migrate, I get an error: ActiveRecord::NODatabaseError role "ubuntu" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I started the postgresql server by doing this:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

then I connected to the service:

```
sudo sudo -u postgres psql
```

then I created a database (i'm trying to add a voting system to my app):

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "votes";
```

but i still have the same problem.

Also, when I do

```
rake db:create
```

I get a role "ubuntu" does not exist error

Here is my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
# default: &default
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# development:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/development.sqlite3

# # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# test:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/test.sqlite3

# production:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/production.sqlite3

# FOR HEROKU -- POSTGRES DB SETUP
# UNCOMMENT WHEN WORKING LOCALLY.
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: votes
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: ubuntu

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: planit_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


# production:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I'm trying to create an ubuntu rold:

```
$ sudo sudo -u postgres psql
psql (9.3.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE ROLE ubuntu SUPERUSER
postgres-# \q
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
```

Comment: Have you configured your databases.yml?

Comment: check `database.yml` and change the username. If you want to connect with user `ubuntu` then you have to create it first in postgres. Check the [create role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-createrole.html) documentation. After you create it make sure you [alter role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterrole.html) with correct permisions.

Comment: yes i connected to the service. and then I did CREATE USER ubuntu SUPERUSER. the usernmae "ubuntu" is in my database.yml file. Still getting same problem

Comment: In Postgres, users and roles are not equivalent. If `CREATE USER` isn't sufficient, you should re-read @radubogdan's comment and look into `CREATE ROLE` and `ALTER ROLE`.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting about `role "ubuntu" does not exist` is because of the user (or `role`) that you are trying to use to access your postgress session from the app.

As your `database.yml` specified

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: votes
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: ubuntu
```

Notice the last line: `username: ubuntu`?

Two ways you can go about this are:

1) Remove that line (maybe comment it out) - This will make your app connect to your postgress session with the default set name (or `role`, as you may want to call it). The default most times will be `postgress` or your username on your machine.

2) create the role `ubuntu` for your postgress. To do this, you can [check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11919677/4330954)

Either of the above two ways should work well for you.

Comment: I had just added the username: ubuntu to the database.yml, thinking it would be a fix. however, i'v deleted it and I still get the same issue of NoDatabseError. I'll try your second option

Comment: I'm confused on what I'm supposed to do. taking your advice, look at what my results are (I edited the question above) when I try to create a new role.

Comment: When you go into `psql` and list all users `\du`, what is the output?

Comment: the only role name listed is postgres

Comment: try to use `postgres` then as the username from inside your `database.ym`. what happens when you do this?

Comment: And also, what are the priviledges for this your `postgres` user? Eg: [check mine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dna2r31ryubog55/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-05%20at%205.59.11%20AM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Use postgres instead, it's default role from Postgre. Or try this one:

```
    sudo su - postgres
    psql template1
```

then

```
    CREATE ROLE ubuntu superuser createdb login;
```

You can check if the role exist or not with command:

```
    \du
```