# error: [Errno 98] Address already in use while installing odoo 10 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo-10

I am installing odoo 10 on ubuntu 16.04. All commands run well during installation. When I start Odoo Server using commands given below:

```
cd /opt/odoo/odoo-10.0 
./odoo-bin
```

I get an error:

```
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

odoo by default run on the 8069 port, so you may find use it by shell command:

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep 8069
```

if need you can run odoo on other port by command:

```
./odoo-bin --longpolling-port 3333
```

Comment: Thank you so much error is finished but now I get another which is:
 "  OperationalError: FATAL:  role "junaid" does not exist  "
what's the solution???

Comment: it is another trouble, unfortunately, i don't know the answer.

Comment: @junaid majeed Check out the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

you are using same port again, so that why this error,we can fix using by below command

**ps aux | grep odoo**

these command shows number process running on you computer which is belong to odoo

**kill -9 process id**