# Error: FATAL: role "login" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, grails, amazon-rds

Some context: I am a novice engineer developing a Grails 3.3.3 app that requires a database connection. Currently, there is an Amazon RDS instance created and configured for this purpose. A proper connection from the application to the db has not been established.

I've confirmed my security configuration is correct, as well as my credentials, since I am able to connect from the shell using the standard `psql` command.

Unless, I've missed something, the RDS [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.PostgreSQL.Connect) provided insight but little help.

I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist) which is helpful, however I (seemingly) don't have operating system privileges as AWS restricts this type of access.

My issue seems it stems from either postgresql or RDS, and not specifically the application.yml configuration from the grails project. Furthermore, I have the necessary dependencies installed for the connection. application.yml is included below:

```
dataSource:
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  logSql: true
  formatSql: true
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  dbCreate: "update"
  url: jdbc:postgresql:endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:port/database
  username: "login"
  password: "password"
```

I have examined the postgres roles and databases. Futhermore, I have created and deleted roles as well as added and revoked various high-level permissions to these roles. I have been unable to log in using any role in the role table; the error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "login" does not exist` indicates it does not exist, however, I have contrary evidence.

```
postgres=> \du
 login        | Create role, Create DB      +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity|
 rds_replication | Cannot login                 | {}
 rds_superuser   | Cannot login                 | {rds_replication,pg_signal_backend}
 rdsadmin        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rdsrepladmin    | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication              | {}
```

The provided stacktrace with the relevant first error:

```
| Running application...
2018-06-22 12:12:20.343 ERROR --- [           main] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "login" does not exist
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:162)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:106)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.proxy(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:95)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:88)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:37)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:38)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.(HibernateDatastore.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:923)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at charity.navigator.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Comment: yes, stacktrace would be helpful, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed! I realized the dataSource.url connection string was misconfigured; it needs two forward slashes.

`jdbc:postgresql://endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:port/database`

The application defaults to a localhost data source when it can't interpret a url string. This was realized when the application tried to locally connect to psql that was not started and caused the error: `Unable to create initial connections of pool. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused.` When running, my local psql did not have the correct roles, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "postgres-extensions" plugin by any chance? Yesterday, I ran into the same exact issue and found that rolling back the version of this plugin to 4.6.1 did the trick. For some reason, the newer versions of the plugin do not play nice with Grails 3.

To rollback, change the line in **build.gradle** that adds the plugin to:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:4.6.1'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using the "postgres-entensions" plugin. My current configuration: `compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2" `