# no root or postgres user available after deploy postgresql by rancher

Tags: postgresql, rancher

I launched a pod in rancher with    docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-10-r0.
The pod can be successfully started and the postgres daemon is started.
However, inside the pod, I got a "I have no name" shell prompt.

The pod log did say creating password for postgres user.
However, I don't have root password, neither do I have sudo, or su to postgres.
The pgsql db is running but cannot be accessed from pgadmin outside the pod.

Comment: Whoever *has* `sudo` rights can easily fix this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11919677/939860. Or (temporarily) activate [`trust` authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html) in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Is there a default root password built in docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-10-r0?

Comment: Postgres does not ship with a default password. I wouldn't know about docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-10-r0.