# Docker compose: Error: role "hleb" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Kindly ask you to help with docker and Postgres.

- I have a local Postgres database and a project on NestJS.
- I killed 5432 port.
- My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.13.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

COPY ./dist ./dist
CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

- My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 9229:9229
    command: yarn start:dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: 'trust'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

- .env

```
DB_TYPE=postgres
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=hleb
DB_NAME=artwine
DB_PASSWORD=Mypassword
```

- running **sudo docker-compose build** - NO ERRORS
- running **sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate** - ERROR

ERROR [ExceptionHandler] role "hleb" does not exist.

I've tried multiple suggestions from existing issues but nothing helped.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Pretty straight forward the Postgres database cluster you are connecting to does not have the `role` `hleb`.  Where `role` in this case is synonymous with user. See [Create Role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) for how to create one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use `sudo` - unless you have to.
- Use the latest Postgres release if possible.

The [Postgresql Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) provides some environment variables, that will help you bootstrapping your database.

Be aware:

> The PostgreSQL image uses several environment variables which are easy to miss. The only variable required is POSTGRES_PASSWORD, the rest are optional.

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

When you do not provide the `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable in the docker-compose.yml file, it will default to `postgres`.

Your .env file used for Docker Compose does not contain the docker specific environment variables.

So amending/extending it to:

```
POSTGRES_USER=hleb
POSTGRES_DB=artwine
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Mypassword
```

should do the trick. You will have to re-create the volume (delete it) to make this work, if the data directory already exists.

Comment: This suggestion solved my problem. Thank you so much and have a nice day.