# Entity framework + postgis Get-Migration fails with Error: 28000: role "my_username" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, postgis

I have a postgis database running using the following [docker-compose file](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml):

```
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  dbbackups:
  postgis-data:

services:

  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:14-3.2
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql
      - dbbackups:/backups
    environment:
      # If you need to create multiple database you can add coma separated databases eg gis,data
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=my_username
      - POSTGRES_PASS=my_password
      - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0
      # Add extensions you need to be enabled by default in the DB. Default are the five specified below
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
    ports:
      - "25432:5432"
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
```

I have an ASP.Net Core Web API project configured to use this database. In `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PerceptionAnnotationServerContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=25432;Database=my_db;Username=my_username;Password=my_password"));
```

If I do `Get-Migration` or `Add-Migration` then `Update-Database` from the VS 2022 pack manager console, I get the error:

> An error occurred while accessing the database. Continuing without the information provided by the database. Error: 28000: role "my_username" does not exist

I initially found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist) on how to add the user. However checking with pgAdmin shows that the role "my_username" already exists and has access to "my_db".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add to the db context:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=25432;Database=my_db;Username=my_username;Password=my_password");
    }
```