# Local DB - "your_postgres_user" does not exist

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, local

I've built an application and when I go to run main.py I'm encountering an error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "your_postgres_user" does not exist
```

I have ensured that my .env file is correctly linked to my main.py file and the environment variables are accurate.

I have ensured that PostgreSQL is correctly installed.

I have ensured that the Postgres user is correct by querying it in terminal via

```
psql postgres

\du
```

My .env file looks like:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=mydatabase
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=developer
```

and my main.py database code looks like:

```
#Create connection to SQLAlchemy Database
DB_USER = os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_PORT = os.getenv('DB_PORT')
DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'
```

My database.py looks like

```
   def get_db_config():
    return {
        'dbname': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'user': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'password': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'port': os.getenv('DB_PORT')
    }

def get_db_connection():
    config = get_db_config()
    return psycopg2.connect(**config)
```

Please let me know if there are any quick fixes here!

Thanks in advance.

------ Edit following comment
[Terminal error after step one of link provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo4Ba.png)

Please see the image above I get from terminal after trying step one of the solution provided - any thoughts here?

----- Edit following another comment
[psql postgres - followed by \du](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW8Tv.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11919391/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not... - I've just added in an edit to the message above with the error. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've also added in what my database.py code looks like

Comment: You're evidently on a Mac, so `sudo -u postgres` isn't a thing - you should be able to just `psql` if you've installed Postgres from e.g. Homebrew. If you're really getting an error that says `your_postgres_user`, then you've pasted in `your_postgres_user` somewhere - you should replace that with whatever is your postgres user...

Comment: I've installed Postgres from Homebrew - so psql works. I've honestly searched thru all my code numerous times (its only 500 or so lines) and I can't for the life of me see any reference to 'your_postgres_user'. Could it be a Psycopg2 error? Because I struggled to install this last week - it failed on a part around 'building wheels'... Not sure if that is helpful at all lol

Comment: I've just added in a second edit to my post wrt the users - so you can see the connection between the .env and the authorised users on Postgres

Comment: I have figured out what the issue is - but I don't know how to fix it! It turns out my .env file and the data within it is not being correctly fetched with the code: DB_USER = os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER') - despite having the .env file correctly setup + import os , from dotenv import load_dotenv and load_dotenv() at the top of my application. I know this is the case as I hard coded the environment variables in and it worked fine

Comment: I fixed it - i'm using from dotenv import dotenv_values rather than from dotenv import load_dotenv - and using get. rather than os.