# My SpringBoot application does not connect to the postgre Database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jobapp
spring.datasource.username = pranav
spring.datasource.password = pranav
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

and here is my dockerfile

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pranav
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pranav
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin          
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

I try to connect to the database that runs on container but i get an error that  `role "pranav" does not exist` but i can connect with the same user through command line .

Comment: have you tried deleting your docker volume and re-running? i.e. stop all your docker containers, then `docker volume prune` and make sure the postgres volume gets deleted. and then re-run things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)