# Postgres database username in database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

How do I find out what is my database's `username` in my local machine? I'm updating my `database.yml` file in my rails application, but anything I try isn't working.

When trying to use `postgres` (or other options such as `mymacusername`) I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Do I need to create it? How? Or can I use an existing username on my computer?

Update: 
I am trying to create a user (this is soon after installation so the issue may be that it doesn't exist yet)
I ran `createuser -s -U $USER`
Name of role to add: `postgres`

But am getting the following error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So this is the problem - How do I make it listen to the correct socket?

Answer (score 1):

if you have root access:

```
sudo -u postgres psql DATABASENAME
```

inside it type

```
\l
```

to show all databases and its users

Comment: I have admin access. I tried that and got `sudo: unknown user: postgres`

Comment: try to look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863770/rails-and-postgresql-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem, but the solution isn't there - how can I find that socket and get it to listen to it? I am trying `sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls` but not sure how to get postgres to talk to it

Comment: `netstat -nlp | grep postgre` . The listening port should be the last number. There should be more than 1 entries in the result

Comment: `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Comment: `Usage: netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
 netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
 netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRt]
 netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
 netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
 netstat -m [-m]
 netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
 netstat -rs [-s]`

Comment: mmm because you're on osx and i'm on linux. try `netstat -l | grep PGSQL`

Comment: Okay yes, I get the listening port - /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 but how do I get the database to talk to it?

Comment: Btw I just posted this as a new question regarding the socket here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/postgresql-socket-not-listening-on-the-right-one

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, you can set the host to the absolute path to the directory of the socket (in this case host = /tmp).  Not very intuitive but it works.

Answer (score 0):

We simply need to create postgres role.
Commands to create a role name postgres:
1.sudo -u postgres psql
2.CREATE ROLE postgres WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password'