# postgres error for rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I was having a rails application, and I want to deploy it in my new laptop ( with ruby and rails installed fresh).

After installing gems and all .. when i goto my rails application folder and ruby `rails s`

Error shows like :

```
/home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': FATAL:  role "insane" does not exist (PG::Error)
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2015430698042624034__prepare__3529665547423141566__callbacks'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/insane/Rails/BACKUP/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/insane/Rails/BACKUP/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/insane/Rails/BACKUP/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/insane/Rails/BACKUP/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have gone through the below link , but even it dint help saying `/Rails/BACKUP$ createdb insane`

createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "insane" does not exist
[(postgreSQL error) FATAL: role "demo" does not exist (PG::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378206/postgresql-error-fatal-role-demo-does-not-exist-pgerror)`

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a user in the database named `insane`.

Open up a terminal and do the following

(the `$` and `psql>` denote the terminal type, not commands that you type)

```
$ psql template1
psql> CREATE USER insane WITH PASSWORD 'some_password';
```

That should create the user for you. Alternatively, if this is on a dev machine, you can just use

```
psql> CREATE USER insane superuser;
```

That will create the user `insane` with all permissions.

**NOTE**

You may first need to be logged in as the `postgres` user.

```
$ sudo su postgres
<password for your account>
```

You will not see your password being typed.

Then you will be able to use the first set of commands above.