# FATAL: Role 'abc' does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I just pulled code from online and tried running it after the usual bundle install. However, I get this error:

> FATAL:  role "abc" does not exist

I understand it is related to postgresql. Checked in gemfile and noticed 2 db gems being installed, have commented out the non pg gem.

Also, browsed around on SO for solution, but I am unable to create the role abc even though I tried following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863770/rails-and-postgresql-role-postgres-does-not-exist). What can I do to resolve my issue. Do I have to create abc, what does it mean?

Also, note that I don't know my su password, thus was unable to follow the post at some point.

Comment: In the source you grabbed online, did you change the database.yml to reflect your specific database and user names for postgres?

Comment: no, i meant to use the one in the database.yml, basically mirror everything

Comment: is there something i should do to set up the database according? I have installed pg gem, what should I do further?

Comment: Ultimately you have to create a postgres user for 'abc' - you can either do that from a command line as you linked SO question suggests - and depending on your setup, you'll need sudo or root -- OR if you know the postgres user information (usually the username is postgres) you can create the new role from within psql i.e. `CREATE USER ben WITH PASSWORD 'BensPassword';`