# Postgres does not create role

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have installed postgres via brew. However, after running `rake db:create` I get error

> role 'posgres' does not exist

I can not run `psql` as role of my user does not exist, which is logical, but I can not login with -u postgres either.
Any suggestions, how to create postgres user ?

Comment: You seems to have typo!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails and PostgreSQL: Role postgres does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863770/rails-and-postgresql-role-postgres-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the service is not running / turned on after instal.

Documentation reference: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-start.html

Then perform initdb /[data location]

Then you will need to sudo to postgres user (the service user) to issue commands to the database.